# Best questions and answers from 3rd quarter of 2020

Tags: discussion, best-of

Some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions and great answers** from the last quarter. There are [204 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-07-01..2020-09-30+is%3Aq) and [408 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2020-07-01..2020-09-30+is%3Aa) to choose from.
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

Comment: Well, I know it would be against Stack Exchange CoC (be friendly, no subtle put-downs) but I wonder if it wouldn't be more popular to introduce nominations for the worst answers, Razzie Awards style...

Comment: It would certainly be more popular, but given the atmosphere on FSE lately, I think some good old *bienveillance* won't hurt! 

Answer (score 3):

Some favourite questions:

- [Pronunciation of IEN](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42843/pronunciation-of-ien)

  - A broader version of a question I asked after being mistaken in my advice to a student. An attempt to find out the logic or system behind something that appears unpredictable.
- [ramer à mort - meaning](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/ramer-%c3%a0-mort-meaning)

  - Interesting idiom; simply enjoyed reading it. I don't usually like "What does this individual phrase mean?" questions, but in this case, the combined idioms "ça rame" and "à mort" make it somewhat opaque for the learner trying to parse from scratch.
- [French pronunciation of Greek letters](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42566/french-pronunciation-of-greek-letters)

  - It's surprisingly difficult to find this information listed despite its usefulness, because searching for relevant terms (on Google at least) produces articles in French about how the Greek letters are pronounced *in Greek*. That yields a good question native speakers can weigh in on without having lots of technical knowledge.
- [Pourquoi les enfants croivent-ils ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42594/pourquoi-les-enfants-croivent-ils)

  - Children's errors tend to be both instructive and funny. You learn a new paradigm and a little bit of acquisition theory too. Also, when I used to write stories and scenes with French dialogue (a task a bit too daunting for me now), this would be the perfect kind of colour that I could incorporate for realism.